# One div scrollable and other fixed

Tags: css, css-position

I am having a CSS issue; See the attached image.

[image]

there have two fixed div.. where i will put my navigation and yellow area is my content area. content area will be scroll if content big..

but now problem i am facing content area position not fit properly. when i make other two div `position: fixed` then issue coming. please see my code and jsfiddle..

**.midarea** this div position not properly fit there. if you see jsfiddle then can under properly..

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/dY6xU/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `.midarea` to be fixed to match the others:

```
.midarea {
    position: fixed;
    left:260px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    ...
}
```

With this your float and width are obsolete (but you can have them if you really want).

Also **please, please** lose every `z-index` and every `float` with a `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`.

**[Visualize](http://jsfiddle.net/Yby9F/)**

Comment: thank u so much.. it work nicely :) i updated code also http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/dY6xU/2/ .. thanks... again.. @Deryck

Answer (score -1):

position:fixed is absolutely OK.
Just calculate the sum of width of both fixed nav-colums and set a padding-left with this calculated width to the div.midarea. So all divs inside the midarea begin right of the fixed colums.

And a z-index higher of the content is needed. e.g. z-index:999;

Comment: if set position:fixed then if i will much content how to scroll ?

Comment: position:fixed just for your two navigation/tab-colums, not for the content, not for .midarea